# Changing Return type of a function in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, return-type, scala-reflect

I need to write a function that has the return type *NodeSeq (scala.xml.NodeSeq)*,
In the below function, I'm trying to get the NodeSeq of an XML file, by evaluating an expression using the below code. The compiler throws type mismatch error.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

def someFunc(params): NodeSeq = {
  some code
  ....
  val evaluator = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
  val data: NodeSeq = evaluator.eval(evaluator.parse(expression))  // return type - Any

  if(data.getClass.getName == scala.xml.NodeSeq) data else NodeSeq.Empty
}
```

the *val data* should ideally contain NodeSeq (from the data I have), but I'm evaluating an expression, the return type of the expression can be anything,

I understand, why I can't return NodeSeq using the above code,
the best I could come up with is the last *if* condition.
Is there anything, that I can do to change the return type of this function to NodeSeq from Any?

Comment: try use [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) instead of checking name of class. Of cource you should not compare String with Class: it's different types.

Comment: Thanks @MikhailIonkin, I'm able to change the return type now. Also, can you please post this as an answer, so that I can accept your solution and close this question.

Comment: Ok, I posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) when the result (or action) depends on the type or value. It is a more powerful version of the `switch`.

The code below was already submitted by Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez in a comment on a deleted answer:

```scala
val data: NodeSeq = evaluator.eval(evaluator.parse(expression)) match {
  case n: NodeSeq => n
  case _ => NodeSeq.Empty
}
```

In some cases the compiler will warn you if you have not considered all possible cases (`match may not be exhaustive`). Both Intellij Idea and SBT will warn you, if you use fruitless type in pattern matching (like `List[String]` instead of `List[Int]`).

You should not compare String (`data.getClass.getName`) with Class (`scala.xml.NodeSeq`), because you will get compile error. It's not recommended use class name to check class (like `data.getClass.getName == "scala.xml.NodeSeq"`), because at least it is not checked by compiler, and because you will get `NullPointerException` if `data == null`.

There is another way: check class by [`isInstanceOf`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Any.html#isInstanceOf[T0]:Boolean). But it is also not recommended, because `isInstanceOf` does not check the type of generics: `List(1).isInstanceOf[List[String]]` will return `true`.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Mikhail, I'm starting to learn Scala, good to know, these details, and don't be sorry, I'm able to clearly understand, what you're saying.